# Accordian with Listview Items Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there anyway to render an accordian with list items from a listview in using jquery mobile?

The following code will NOT render "section 2" when I add a listview to it

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <p>I'm the collapsible content in a set so this feels like an accordion. I'm open by default because I have the <code>data-collapsed="false"</code> attribute.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">

    <ul data-role="listview" id="myAppsSectionGridTable">
    <li><a href="pa.aspx">
        <img src="images/gf.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon">IT Change Controls<span class="ui-li-count">
            4</span> 
            </a>
            </li>
              <li><a href="pa.aspx">
        <img src="images/gf.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon">Expense<span class="ui-li-count">
            8</span> 
            </a>
            </li>
              <li><a href="pa.aspx">
        <img src="images/gf.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon">Seminar<span class="ui-li-count">
            6</span> 
            </a>
            </li>
              <li><a href="PendingApprovals.aspx">
        <img src="images/gf.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon">Indirect PR<span class="ui-li-count">
            4</span> 
            </a>
            </li>
              <li><a href="pa.aspx">
        <img src="images/gf.png" alt="" class="ui-li-icon">PTO<span class="ui-li-count">
            2</span> 
            </a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

```
        </div>
```

Comment: So you mean having a bunch of listviews inside of an accordion right?

Comment: yea and the listitems have images links etc..Like the markup above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you mean something like this.

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jjKHW/)

Comment: Kinda.Can you add the "count bubble" and an image to the section header?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jquery accordian that's really easy to use and works fully, I've used it on a couple sites.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Comment: He's referring to jQuery mobile